# what is the best data structure for moving nth element to the front?

Tags: algorithm, sorting

so I need to move n-th element from beginning and move it to the front (and shifting 0,..,n-1 items to the right). What would be best data structure to use and how should I go about it?

I already thinking about skiplist, but don't know how to get O(log n) for access via index. Are there any better things (trees or something) I should use?

Thanks in advance..

Language: C++

Disclaimer: Yes, this is homework.

Comment: I'd just go for a double-linked list where each node has two pointers - one to the next and the other to the previous. But as for O(log n), I don't konw how effective this is.

Comment: I guess his homework demands that the (n-1) first items be shifted to the right. Or else, it's trivial.

Comment: yes, that's right.. array is just to slow because of the need to copy LOT of item (500000) in worst case.. I know there is O(log n) solution but I cannot think of it :/

Comment: [Indexable skiplist](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skip_list#Indexable_skiplist)?

Comment: I'm assuming the array isn't sorted?

Comment: You can not tell whether or not using an Array might be slow or not, because you won’t even know if actual “copying” has to occur or not, without looking at a specific implementation of an “Array”. Purely algorithmically your question makes little sense – discussing this for a specific implementation/programming language could make a little more.

Comment: you can always use ordinary array and use the http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/nth_element/ algorithm which is O(log n) in finding the nth element.

Comment: So do you mean the nth element in the array, as they are stored, or the nth smallest element?

Comment: @EvgenyKluev I'm trying to implement this but so far failing miserably :D

Comment: @CBroe oh, yes, I'm using c++

Comment: I dont know how Arraylist is programmed but I would go for it. As CBroe says, it is implementation issue. equivalent of that is in c++, vectors

Comment: What other operations do you need, and what are their complexities?

Comment: @smttsp vector is a bad choice, they are "relatively efficient adding or removing elements from its end", but I need to add element to the beginning

Comment: @CBroe, the question makes perfect sense from a language-agnostic point of view. One of the characteristics of data structures is that they can be implemented in any language and their time complexity remains the same because it is governed by the theory of the data structure and not the actual implementation. If you mean actual timing then of course it matters but at the data structure level it should be the same

Comment: you could make use of an [order statistics tree](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Order_statistic_tree) that supports efficient (logarithmic) order/rank operations. it could be implemented as an augmentation over a balanced BST say red-black tree so your insertion/deletion also completes in logarithmic time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use any balanced binary tree (e.g. a red-black tree) where in each node you cache the number of items stored in that subtree. The items themselves can be stored in the leaves. For indexed lookup, you compare the index with the size of the left subtree. If it's smaller, it's there. Otherwise it's in the right side, so subtract the size of the left subtree from the index to get the index relative to the right subtree. Then recurse. Since the tree is balanced, this gives you O(log n).

For the other operations you can use the existing algorithms for red-black trees. You just need some small modifications to keep track of the size. For example, to move an item to the front, you first find it using the algorithm described above, then delete it and reinsert it at the front. Each of these steps is O(log n), so the total runtime is also O(log n).

Comment: will try, it looks interesting, thanks for now ^_^

Comment: I realize this isn't intended to be a complete and detailed answer, but I think the instruction for indexed lookup is misleading. For the recursive part, you first need to decrement the index to be looked up by `size_ of_left_ subtree + 1` before going down into the right subtree.

Comment: @G.Bach: Yes, you're right. That detail is important. Although for the method I had in mind, the data is stored in the leaves so there is no `+ 1`. However, whether you store the data in the nodes or in the leaves doesn't really matter (since you only need the size to choose a branch). Either way works fine.

Answer (score 2):

These questions always centre on a fundamental principle, you can think of it as the "no free lunch" of computer science: the tradeoff between time and space.

If you want to do something very fast, you need to consume more space, and vice versa.

For example, an array is the best-case for small space, but the moment you need to move something, it is horrendous. Hashtable is the best case for fast access, but consumes an excessive amount of wasted space.

So you have to decide what is more important, space economy or time economy.

In this case, if you are looking for O(log n) for indexed lokup, you can use a skip-list or indexed skip list. These data structures provide the benefits of linked list (easy to move the n-th element to the front, just change two pointers) with the benefits of an array (indexed lookup), at the cost of space (more pointers are stored to the "skipped" lists).

Comment: You mention a hash table, but how would you solve a problem using that? Or am I reading *around* what you're trying to say.

Comment: @Dukeling considering hashtables aren't designed to keep an order on the elements they contain, I think it was just used as an example regarding where we gain a better time complexity at the cost of space.

Comment: @G.Bach spot on. Was using the hash table to illustrate the principle. For clarity's sake in this case a hashtable is not a useful data structure to use

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can go for LinkedHashMap kind of DS. In java there is an inbuilt implementation of  [LinkedHashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html). So moving the last object at first poition involves removing the last one and then adding it to same DS. Searching can be done in O(1) time again. In other languages also its not a tough thing to implement using LinkedList as primary DS augmented by by a HashMap DS along with it.

Comment: Operation "get n-th element from beginning" would take O(n) time when using LinkedHashMap.

Comment: Not necessarily if you have your own implementation of list augmented by HashTable/HashMap where you maintain reference to first and last elements just like in a standard Queue. So it can be achieved in O(1) as such

Comment: No.  "Hash table + linked list" combination is not enough to solve the problem with sublinear time of all required operations.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about the space complexicity but u can use an array of pointer and linklist to do the same in O(1) time(you want data to be in front as u said in case of array). Make a linklist of the numbers and an array of the same size that store the address of the linklist node in the same order.For any nth value, pick the address of nth node and 1st node from the array and replace the numbers of those nodes................

Comment: but I need to shift the rest, not switch two values..

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a doubly linked list will do :) When you use a doubly linked list:

The indexing takes O(n) since we need to traverse all elements from the beginning up to the desired index.

The removal operation is straightforward and only takes O(1).

The operation of moving the desired element at the front also takes O(1).

Overall, you get ~O(n) operations...

Comment: O(n) can be done much more simplier with basic dynamic array...

Comment: Removing an element in the middle of an array however forces you to shift all of the trailing elements to take the place of the deleted element...

Comment: yes, but it doesn't matter if you spent O(n) on indexing or moving, you still need O(n)..